# How to unit test a constant that defines an implementation detail?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

How do I unit test a constant that defines an implementation detail?
And should I?

For instance, let's say I have the following class:

```cs
class A 
{
   private Cache _cache;
   const int timeToLiveInCache = 30; // 30 seconds of TTL

   A()
   {
      _cache = new Cache(timeToLiveInCache);
   }
}
```

In my unit test, how can I test that my TTL is indeed 30 seconds?

The `Cache` class has been tested and I know that whatever TTL I input will work as intended, but I want a unit test to make sure that the class `A` actually uses a TTL of 30 seconds. Is it even a good idea to unit test that?

Comment: Could you explain why the specific value 30 seconds is important? Is this an external requirement that ought to be verified? Why is that value important? Would `31` also work? Why not?

Comment: you have to mock the system time

Comment: @amon : basically the value of 30 secs was previously a few seconds, which caused issues because our server kep reloading tons of data and we had poor performances. With around 30 secs we measured that we get correct performances and no bottleneck, etc. So this test is made to ensure that the TTL is set to "around" this value

Comment: Ah, so you really want to test that the TTL is set to some sane number? E.g. `assert 0 <= TTL <= half an hour // see bug #1234`

Comment: @amon yes exactly

Comment: You could abstract the creation of the `Cache` behind a `Factory`, and mock out the behavior of that `Factory` in your unit tests of `A` to check that proper values were used to create the `Cache`.  Or you will need the tests of `A` to go through the logic of the Cache again to make sure that you use a good value (duplicate testing.... boo....)

Comment: If you export the expire date you can make a relevant check. Like http has an expires header. You can check if that date is enough in the future.

Comment: *"And should I?"* - only if designing, writing and maintaining the test provides more benefits than it costs you time and money. For example, it may not be worth the effort if the component is non-critical or if integration tests and/or manual tests cover this area anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Try working at a higher level -- what use case that the business cares about will fail if TTL isn't 30 seconds?

More generally:

Don't write unit tests for things that can't fail; it annoys the pig.

Writing tests that verify a specific implementation is usually a bad idea.  When you later come up with a better way to implement what you need, all of those tests are going to get thrown away (or not -- maybe somebody is going to have to go through them to try to figure out if there is any business value left hiding in them -- more waste!).

Which isn't to say that it isn't nice to have some block and tackle when you are down in the trenches trying to get something working the first time.  For instance, when you are doing a spike of some functionality, tests that are specific to the implementation can be a comfort, as they more quickly help you identify *what* has gone wrong, rather than simply what requirement has been missed.

For instance, you wouldn't write a test to verify [getRandomNumber()](https://xkcd.com/221/) That's just deranged.  Instead, you write tests that ensure that any implementation that passes the tests are acceptable to the business.

Consider sort, for example.  Unless what you are actually shipping is the *World's Best Web-Scale Bubble Sort*, you don't care about the implementation details under the hood.  What you care about is whether or not a bunch of pathological use cases produce acceptable results.  You care about whether certain pathological data cases cause your comparator to become unstable, and so on.

That said, certain kinds of things are a real pain to test.  Caches would be one of them; a cache is basically a memory/computation tradeoff, usually made to improve an SLA, rather than to provide additional correctness guarantees.  So a durable unit test for this might look like

```
given(User.hasBeenIdleFor(MINUTES(29)))
.when(User.loadsPage())
.expect(Probability(Page.loadsWithin(MILLISECONDS(1)))>Probability.NINES(3));
```

and then you try to figure out how to implement that test to satisfy

```
Probability.testExecutesWithin(SECONDS(1)) > Probability.NINES(2);
```

Whee - fun times.

Comment: I think I agree with “don't write tests for things that can't fail”, but you seem to make a general case against unit tests in favour of high-level feature tests. In general, this is the way to go, but discards the value of careful unit tests: asserting not that required *features* are implemented, but that the system under test is *correct*. And RNGs should be carefully tested, since they are so important. If for a known state an algo does not produce the next expected number, it is broken!

Comment: @amon Unit tests are "feature" tests (mind the quotes) in the sense that unit tests test the features (i.e. behavior) of the test subject. The tested behavior is usually not outward (i.e. towards the end user), but it is outwards in the sense of the public/private access modifier distinction (i.e. towards consumers of the tested class). In that regard, this answer is correct in focusing on the higher level "feature" (behavior) view over a test subject, instead of being bogged down into implementation details.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I unit test a constant that defines an implementation detail?

The short answer here is that **you don't test implementation details** (and constants are an implementation detail).

Instead, **you test public behavior**, i.e. the outwardly observable response from the tested object.

> The Cache class has been tested and I know that whatever TTL I input will work as intended

That's good news. For the current topic, that means your unit testing is done.

> ...but I want a unit test to make sure that the class A actually uses a TTL of 30 seconds.

That's not a unit test. At best, it's a feature test, provided that it's part of the requirements of the application.

However, if "30 seconds" is not explicitly part of the software spec, then it's an arbitrary configuration value, and configuration values should not be tested. Configurability itself should be tested (i.e. different behavior based on different config settings), but not the existence of a specific value.

Such a test would essentially be testing a declaration, e.g.

```
var foo = 2;

Assert.AreEqual(foo, 2);
```

This is not a meaningful test and should not be written.

---

Should you write a feature test for this, it's important to remember that you **test behavior (= adherence to specs), not configuration settings**.

Therefore, you shouldn't be testing the constant's value. You should simply run an actual test (integration, not unit) and see what happens after 31 seconds. If the cache is still valid, the test fails. Similarly, run the same test but see what happens after 29 seconds - if the cached is invalid, the test fails.
I used 29/31 seconds for the sake of example, but how precise your behavioral tests are depends on what is meaningful to you.

Answer (score 2):

The unit tests need access to this constant, in order to verify that cache entries aren't removed before their time to live has expired. The actual value given is irrelevant, I'd think.

Therefore: make this constant public and document it. After all, the time to live is not a secret but results in externally observable consequences. If you like, you can also note that the specific value of this constant is unspecified and subject to change. This avoids duplicating the constant value in your code and in your tests. If you had duplicated such information, your tests would be more fragile.

Bad test:

```cs
mockTime = 0;
cache.put(value);
assert cache.contains(value);

mockTime += 30;

assert !cache.contains(value);
```

Better test:

```cs
mockTime = 0;
cache.put(value);
assert cache.contains(value);

mockTime += cache.TIME_TO_LIVE;

assert !cache.contains(value);
```

Comment: This is not answering the OP's question.  They already know the Cache works, they want to test if the "application" is using a valid value for the cache.